# Pass 2D real array to a function in System Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to pass 2D real array to an SV function and return the same but I'm not able to execute this task successfully. Here is a simple reproducible code:

```
module Two_d_array_pass();

real x[2][2]='{'{1.0,2.0},'{3.0,4.0}};
real y[2][2]='{'{2.0,2.0},'{2.0,2.0}};
real z[2][2];
int i,j;

initial begin
    foreach(x[i,j]) $display("x[%0d][%0d]=%0f",i,j,x[i][j]);
    foreach(y[i,j]) $display("y[%0d][%0d]=%0f",i,j,y[i][j]);
    z=mult(x,y);
end

function real mult(x,y);
    real c[2][2];
    int i,j;    
    foreach(c[i,j]) 
        c[i][j]=x[i][j]*y[i][j];
    return c;
endfunction

endmodule
```

and here is the error I get:

```
file: Two_d_array_pass.sv
                c[i][j]=x[i][j]*y[i][j];
                        |
xmvlog: *E,DIMERR (Two_d_array_pass.sv,18|10): Bit-select or part-select dimensions do not match declaration.
                c[i][j]=x[i][j]*y[i][j];
                                |
xmvlog: *E,DIMERR (Two_d_array_pass.sv,18|18): Bit-select or part-select dimensions do not match declaration.
```

Can anyone correct the code to achieve this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the arguments to be 2x2 dimensional as well.

```
function real mult(real x[2][2],y[2][2]);
```

But you also need to do it for the return type, but because of syntax limitations, unpacked array need a typedef for the return type.

```
typedef real real2x2[2][2];
function real2x2 mult(real x[2][2],y[2][2]);
```

Then you might as well use the typedef everywhere

```
module Two_d_array_pass();
  typedef real real2x2[2][2];
  real2x2 x='{'{1.0,2.0},'{3.0,4.0}};
  real2x2 y='{'{2.0,2.0},'{2.0,2.0}};
  real2x2 z;

initial begin
    foreach(x[i,j]) $display("x[%0d][%0d]=%0f",i,j,x[i][j]);
    foreach(y[i,j]) $display("y[%0d][%0d]=%0f",i,j,y[i][j]);
    z=mult(x,y);
end

  function real2x2 mult(real2x2 x,y);  
    foreach(x[i,j]) 
        mult[i][j]=x[i][j]*y[i][j];
  endfunction

endmodule
```

P.S. you do not declare the iterating variables `i` and `j` separately, they are implicit and local to the scope of the `foreach` statement. If you declare them separately, they become extra variables unused by the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Thank you very much Dave, code excecuted successfully after these changes.  Nice to learn about i and j in foreach loop. Also no need to declare mult[i][j]? Does it return mult[i][j] automatically? If I have have two statements inside foreach, lets say mult2[i][j]=mult[i][j]+1.0 then what will this function return?

Comment: In Verilog, the name of the function is an implicit variable with the return value type. If the function ends without using a `return` statement, that implicit variable is used as the return value. In your example, that implicit variable is also a variable with a static lifetime.